# Kafka Authentication Via Signed Certificate

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, keystore, truststore

I have 2 Kafka clusters on 2 different environments. Each is configured for SSL using a keystore.jks & truststore.jks.

Each truststore is signed by an organisation root CA.

The problem is I can use the keystores from environment 1 in a client and connect to environment 2.

This is a big security vulnerability as access to the environments should be well separated.

I assume this is because both truststores are signed by the same root CA?

Comment: Yes. You still have ACLs using the identity (principal) to prevent any operations (read/produce/describe etc.), no? You could introduce an intermediate CA for each environment (truststores would be signed with them). You could write a custom Authorizer (broker side) to enforce certain DN only for instance, or whatever logic you want.

Comment: @StéphaneD.thanks

Answer (score 0):

The truststore is used to authenticate. The principle (CN name) of the keystore key is used to authorise.

It's expected for client & server truststores to contain the same root certificate.

ACLs muust be enabled.

I wrote an article about it [here](https://medium.com/@gregory.clinker/kafka-acl-with-mtls-8b640457b6c2)

Key Server Config See [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-demo-ssl-authentication.html)

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
super.users=User:CN=Essexboy1
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
ssl.client.auth=required
```